# Custom Post Type Loop with Query Var

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, multi-taxonomy-query

**Goal:** Loop through custom post type (insurance products) and get only insurance types for that state based on a query var.

**Post type:** insurance_products

**Taxonomies:** state, insurer, insurance-type

I want to skip over the insurance type if the state does not have any insurance products for a product type.

**Example:** http://agencyrmnew.wpengine.com/insurance-by-state?state=or

As you can see there are insurance types that are empty, while the ones that are not contain the right data set.

My data set for this query is:

[insurance-data-set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8ovZ.png)

If feel like I am close but I could be way off.

```
    <div class="theme-page-wrapper mk-grid vc_row-fluid no-padding insurance">

    <?php
    $insurance_types = get_terms('insurance-type');

    foreach($insurance_types as $insurance_type) {
        wp_reset_query();
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'insurance_products',
          'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'insurance-type',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $insurance_type->slug,
                ),
            ),
         );

         $type_loop = new WP_Query($args);

         if($type_loop->have_posts()) {

            $state = get_query_var('state',FALSE);

            echo '<div class="ins-type-wrapper">';
            echo '<h2 class="ins-type-header ' . strtolower($insurance_type->name) . '">' . $insurance_type->        name . '</h2>';

            while($type_loop->have_posts()) : $type_loop->the_post();
            if (has_term( $state, 'state')) {
                    if (get_the_terms($post->ID, 'insurer') ) {
                    $taxonomy_ar = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'insurer');

                      $output = '<ul class="insurer-list">';
                      foreach ($taxonomy_ar as $taxonomy_term) {
                        $output .= '<li>'. $taxonomy_term->name .'</li>';
                      }
                      $output .= '</ul>';

                      echo $output;
                        }
                    }
            endwhile;
            echo '</div>';
            }
    }
    ?>

    </div>
```

Hope I am clear enough, any help appreciated. As a side note I also considered hiding empty containers with jQuery but wasn't sure if that was the best option.

## Update

I am using jQuery to hide the empty boxes for now. Help still needed.